# this.someFunction(params) is not a function in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am working with `d3.js` in an Angular 4 app. I am trying to call a function, but it throws me an error as `ERROR TypeError: this.highlightNodes is not a function`.

Here's the code, I was working on:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare let d3:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.networkGraph();
  }

  networkGraph() {
    d3.netJsonGraph("../assets/json/network.json",
      {
        el: "#randomDiv",
        onClickNode: function (url, opts) {
          //Here's the error being thrown
          this.highlightNodes(url, "nodes", true);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  highlightNodes(url, type, initial) {
    console.log("Its working");
  }
}
```

Using `bind(this)` is not helping because it is binding locally. Please help me resolve this as how to call the function the proper way.

Comment: You are calling a method inside a click handler which is not an arrow function. This will change the context. Try `nClickNode: (url, opts) => {}`

Comment: There must be dupe for `this` (pun intended) :)

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the **`onClickNode`** in this case, use arrow function:

```
onClickNode: (url, opts) => {
   //Here's the error being thrown
   this.highlightNodes(url, "nodes", true);
}
```

Comment: Have you posted answer from phone?

Comment: @Rajesh haha ! how do you know? anyway updated it

Comment: A user with your rep must know tricks and importance to format answer. So if the formatting is off, it means you are using phone and it becomes difficult to format there.

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function to preserve the context

```
onClickNode: (url, opts) => {
    this.highlightNodes(url, "nodes", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `function` keyword, it hides the scope of `this`. Use arrow function instead.

Replace this line:

```
onClickNode: function (url, opts) {
```

... with this:

```
onClickNode: (url, opts) => {
```